# Add a random value for a key in "-runproperties" in a "*.bndrun" file

Tags: java, gradle, bndtools

When I am running tests using [`bnd`](https://bnd.bndtools.org/) (from the Bndtools project) through gradle, I would like to set a random value in `test.bndrun`:

```
-runproperties: \
    osgi.instance.area=random_value
```

Where `random_value` would be something random (like `"area_" + <currentTimeMillis>`).

Is there a possibility to express that without having a script or a gradle task to modify the `test.bndrun` file?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this:

In the `test.bndrun` I have:

```
-runproperties: \
    osgi.instance.area=area_${randomTimestamp}
```

And in the Gradle Task, I prepare the value `randomTimestamp`:

```
def testOSGi = tasks.register('testOSGi', aQute.bnd.gradle.TestOSGi) {
    dependsOn resolve
    bundles = files(sourceSets.osgiTest.runtimeClasspath, configurations.archives.artifacts.files)
    bndrun = file('test.bndrun')
    properties = ['randomTimestamp': System.currentTimeMillis()]
}
```